# ASP.NET Grid.MVC Html.Actionlink wont want to work

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, grid.mvc

Today i wanted to add a Details Link to my Grid.MVC Grid. The Problem is: It doesent want to get the id -> eg Model.ID can be listed, but  in RenderValueAs, it is no member from x. I tried Model.id and modelitem.id... 
What am I doing wrong?

Many Thanks!

View:

```
    @ModelType IEnumerable(Of WebApplication2.Datenbank.Dezernate)
@imports GridMVC.html
@Code
    ViewData("Title") = "Index"
End Code
<html>
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Gridmvc.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/bootstrap.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/gridmvc.min.js")"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width:500px;">

        @Html.Grid(Model).Columns(Function(modelitem)
                                      'Erstellt das Grid für die anzeige der Geräte
                                      modelitem.Add(Function(model) model.ID).Titled("ID")
                                      modelitem.Add(Function(model) model.Dezernat).Titled("Dezernato")
                                      modelitem.Add(Function(model) model.Rechner).Titled("Rechner").SetWidth(20)
                                      modelitem.Add(Function(model) model.Scan).Titled("Scan").SetWidth(20)
                                      modelitem.Add().Encoded(False).Sanitized(False).RenderValueAs(Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", New With {.id = Model.id})) <-- Here is the unknown Member Model.id
                                  End Function
                                      ).WithPaging(10).Sortable(True)
```

Model:

```
Namespace Controllers
Public Class HomeController
    Inherits Controller

    Private db As New TempDbContext
    ' GET: Home
    Function Index(ByVal id As Integer?) As ActionResult
        Dim db As New TempDbContext
        ViewBag.DropdownDezernate = New SelectList(db.Dezernate1, "ID", "Rechner")
        Return View(db.Dezernate1.ToList())
    End Function

    Function Details(ByVal id As Integer?) As ActionResult
        If IsNothing(id) Then
            Return New HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
        End If
        Dim dezernate As Dezernate = db.Dezernate1.Find(id)
        If IsNothing(dezernate) Then
            Return HttpNotFound()
        End If
        Return View(dezernate)
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't find the doc for the VB version, but in C#, `RenderValueAs` takes a `Func<T, string>`parameter.

So (sorry if my syntax is wrong, but I guess you'll get the idea)

```
RenderValueAs(Function(model) Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", New With {.id = model.id}))
```

Comment: Now it shows no errors and it started debugging!

vut now it shows something weird: eg <a href="/Home/Details/13">Details</a> and no link... strange